# Data binding between sibling custom elements

Tags: javascript, polymer

There are two child custom elements inside parent custom element. I don't know if it's even possible, but what I am trying to achieve is when "value" changes, and "prop" changes as a result of binding, I need "feat1" to change accordingly equating to the value of "prop".

parent-element:

```
<dom-module id="parent-element">
  <template>
    <first-child prop={{value}}></first-child>
    <second-child feat1={{prop}}></second-child>
      In parent-element
      <h1>{{value}}</h1>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "parent-element",
      properties: {
        value: {
          type: String
        }
      },
      valueChanged:function(){
        console.log("value changed");
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

first-child:

```
<dom-module id="first-child">
  <template>
    <p>first element.</p>
    <h2>{{prop}}</h2>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "first-child",
      properties:{
        prop:{
          type:String,
          notify:true
        }
      },
        ready:function(){
          this.prop = "property"; //this is just example, in reality it gets data from elsewhere
        }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

second-child:

```
<dom-module id="second-child">
  <template>
    <p>Second element.</p>
    <h2>{{feat1}}</h2>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "second-child",
      properties:{
        feat1:{
          type:String,
          notify:true,
          value:"initial value"
        }
      },
        ready:function(){
         this.addEventListener("feat1-changed",this.myAct);
        },
        myAct:function(){
          console.log("feat1-changed ",this.feat1);
        }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Here is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/p7R8BqJJfoYMVA3t3DbX?p=preview)

Comment: The listener of the second-child is useless because the event is never fired. @zerodevx made for you a very nice answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can. Some issues with your code:

1. From the parent element, bind `prop` in `<first-child>` and `feat1` in `<second-child>` to the same `value`.
2. Use `observer` defined in the `properties` object to listen for changes.
3. Set up `<first-child>` to be a one-way bind from child to parent.
4. Set up `<second-child>` to be a one-way bind from parent to child.

Putting it all together:

`<parent-element>`:

```
<dom-module id="parent-element">

  <template>
    <first-child prop={{value}}></first-child>
    <second-child feat1=[[value]]></second-child>

    <div>parent-element: <b><span>[[value]]</span></b></div>
    <div id="log"></div>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "parent-element",
      properties: {
        value: {
          type: String,
          observer: "valueChanged"
        }
      },
      valueChanged: function (n, o) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = "value changed in parent from "+o+" to "+n;
        Polymer.dom(this.$.log).appendChild(el);
      }

    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

`<first-child>`:

```
  <template>
    <div>first-child: <b><span>{{prop}}</span></b>
      <button on-tap="btnTapped">change 'prop' inside first-child</button>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "first-child",
      properties:{
        prop:{
          type:String,
          notify:true,
          value: "first_child_default"
        }
      },
      btnTapped: function () {
        this.prop = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

`<second-child>`:

```
<dom-module id="second-child">
  <template>
    <div>second-child: <b><span>{{feat1}}</span></b></div>
    <div id="log"></div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "second-child",
      properties:{
        feat1:{
          type:String,
          value:"second_child_default", // you should never see this since default value is passed in from parent
          observer: "feat1Changed"
        }
      },
      feat1Changed: function(n, o) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = "feat1 changed in second-child from "+o+" to "+n;
        Polymer.dom(this.$.log).appendChild(el);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/pONoTxdCDn6jj5axoap1?p=preview

Let me know if this is the correct behaviour you are trying to achieve.